# How to aggregate cycles in a sequence?

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph-algorithm

I have a vector of pairs representing hops between nodes which I would like to collapse when there are cycles (as in aggregate time between the hops in a cycle to display it as just one). So, for example, The path A --> B --> C --> D --> B --> C --> D --> E traverses the subpath B--> C --> D twice, so in my structure I would have something like:

```
(A,B,1)(B,C,3)(C,D,2)(D,B,4)(B,C,5)(C,D,8)(D,E,6)
```

which I would ideally reduce to:

```
(A,B,1)(B,C,3+5)(C,D,2+8)(D,E,6)
```

storing also the 4 from D to B (loop-back edge time) to aggregate separately and be able to display B --> C --> D in a condensed way (the aggregated edge times and an aggregated loop-back time for all the D-->B instances alongside a count of how many times we looped)

How can I go about this?

Comment: Duration between the nodes. But this can represent anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for a **suffix array** or **suffix tree**.
Just produce tokens (in this case (from, to) ) and put it in the Suffix Array or Suffix Tree. Then you can get the pairs.
Simple but not efficietn way:

produce tokens, produce all suffixes of this tokenstream. sort them. and then you have all common subsequences in that sorted list near each other (tokenstream length - tokenstream suffix length = position)
You could do the sorting with quicksort for example, or you just looking for a suffix array implemantation. Suffix Arrays could be constructed in *O(n)* and with *O(n)* space. And finding **maximal pairs/repeats** (thats what you want) can be done in *O(n+k)* (where n = tokennumber, and k = cycles in your list)

Perhaps [**this**](http://docs.seqan.de/seqan/dev/DEMO_Maximal+_Repeats.html) helps. Then you could produce a tokenstream like: ABCDBCDE

Quick and dirty solution is [here](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/63suffix/SuffixArray.java.html)

Answer (score 1):

Basically you go through the path, and store each edge like this ( (A, B), 1 ) in a `map`, and all the discovered node in a `set`

- whenever you encounter an edge that has its destination point as an already discovered node, you know it's a loop-back edge.
- whenever you encounter a same edge, add up its value in your `map`

Comment: So you would get B->C as a subpath aswell, but he only wants B->C->D, because B->C is not a cycle ;) But nevertheless, it could be a cycle, so you cant go for the maximum length of all found 'cycle-candidates' in your algorithm

Comment: I ended up doing something similar where I keep a map of the index position and absorb out the value of an edge into the next edge leaving the former one in a "deprecated state" and leaving 'loopback' nodes with a transition counter. Thanks, I wish I could accept both answers.

Comment: Hmm, then you should have accepted this answer, because it looks like your liking this more. But suffix arrays aren't that difficult (if you wanna do them on your own and its ok to locate n^2 memory, they are really easy to implement). And that library i linked you should work aswell (and then you wont have that memory problem)